# Como agrupar notificações

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Quero fazer um sistema de notificações que se agrupam quando são o mesmo tipo, como as do Facebook. Por enquanto tenho a tabela com as seguintes colunas:

*user_id* (pessoa que recebe a notificação),

*icon* (Geralmente a foto de perfil de outro usuário),

*description* (a descrição do que se refere a notificação),

*registry* (data de registro),

*seen* (um booleano que verifica se a pessoa já visualizou)

**Como eu crio as notificações?** Bom, isso acontece na hora que a ação é executada. Por exemplo, eu clico no botão de seguir Fulano, dentro da função eu registro a notificação, assim:

*user_id*: Id do usuário que eu segui,

*icon*: Minha foto de perfil,

*description*: **Insanity** começou a seguir você!,

*registry*: CURRENT_TIME(),

*seen*: 0

Tenho dois problemas principais:

- Se eu ficar clicando no botão de seguir várias vezes, vai enviar várias notificações.
- O problema do agrupamento: Se mais de uma pessoa seguir, vamos supor que 1000 pessoas façam isso, vai aparecer 1000 notificações. Como agrupar igual o Facebook, exemplo: "Geraldo, Thiago e mais 998 pessoas começaram a seguir você!".

Comment: acho que a logica do face book é caso tenha mais de x notificações ele ao invés de exibir todas ele vai exibir a ultima e quantas outras notificações tem do mesmo tipo

Comment: isso é meio complexo. Mas vc vai precisar mudar a estrutura do db: criar uma tabela com os tipos de atividade e então relacioná-las com a sua tabela atual (ao invés do campo description). Isso vai ajudar o servidor a comparar os registros: é muito mais rápido verificar dois ints que duas strings. (veja sobre normalização do banco)

Answer (score 0):

Utilize a cláusula `GROUP BY`, que é utilizada para agrupar (ou agregar) as linhas da tabela segundo um critério escolhido pelo utilizador, podendo depois ser aplicada uma função de grupo a cada um dos grupos. Usando `GROUP BY` não é possível selecionar linhas individuais.

O exemplo abaixo determina o salário médio de cada função (JOB):

```
SELECT job, AVG(sal)
FROM emp
GROUP BY job;


JOB       AVG(SAL)               
--------- ----------
CLERK     1037,5                 
SALESMAN  1400                   
PRESIDENT 5000                   
MANAGER   2758,3 
ANALYST   3000                   

5 rows selected
```